# Find maximum value in a nested dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, max

I am having trouble understanding how to pull the maximum value of a nested dictionary when it is structured as so:

```
dict = {'City': {1: {'avg_dur': 10.58568297387339,
                 'n_trips': 1901,
                 'tot_dur': 20123.383333333313},
             2: {'avg_dur': 12.25947507658035,
                 'n_trips': 2394,
                 'tot_dur': 29349.183333333356},
             3: {'avg_dur': 12.95495652953303,
                 'n_trips': 3719,
                 'tot_dur': 48179.48333333334}}}
```

I am trying to extract the key for the maximum 'avg_trips' function. In the snippet above, I would expect the answer to return 3. I think I need to use lambda here, but I'm not sure how that works with nested dictionaries to this level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `max` with `key`

**Ex:**

```
dict = {'City': {1: {'avg_dur': 10.58568297387339,
                 'n_trips': 1901,
                 'tot_dur': 20123.383333333313},
             2: {'avg_dur': 12.25947507658035,
                 'n_trips': 2394,
                 'tot_dur': 29349.183333333356},
             3: {'avg_dur': 12.95495652953303,
                 'n_trips': 3719,
                 'tot_dur': 48179.48333333334}}}

print(max(dict["City"].items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['n_trips'])[0])
```

**Output:**

```
3
```

Comment: Thanks! Are you able to explain what's happening here "key=lambda x: x[1]['n_trips'])[0])?

Comment: `dict["City"].items()` returns you a tuple and......i am use lambda to extract tuple[1] which is your dict and the use the required key  in your case `n_trips`

Answer (score 0):

You could also sort the keys by `n_trips` and take the last one:

```
>>> sorted(mydict['City'].keys(), key=lambda x: mydict['City'][x]['n_trips'])[-1]
3
```